# AS3 - How to determine if mx classes/libraries are supported?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, class, actionscript

I'm writing a helper class and I want it to be used in both **flex** and pure **actionscript** projects. For example:

```
public static function listenToPositionAndSize(control:DisplayObject):void
{
      if (mxLibrariesSupported)
      {
            control.addEventListener(mx.events.ResizeEvent.RESIZE, onControlResize);
            control.addEventListener(mx.events.MoveEvent.MOVE, onControlMove);
      }
      else
      {
            control.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.RESIZE, onControlResize);
            control.addEventListener(flash.events.Event.ENTER_FRAME, onControlMove);
      }
}
```

If the code above could work; this class could be used in both pure AS3 and Flex projects. And pure AS3 projects wouldn't complain about the missing mx libraries...

I guess, something like the code below would work if it could compile but;

```
public static function mxLibrariesSupported():Boolean
{
      try
      {
            var e:mx.events.FlexEvent = 
                     new mx.events.FlexEvent(mx.events.FlexEvent.CHANGING);
            return true;
      }
      catch(error:Error){ }
      return false;
}
```

Is there a clearer way? a built-in function or smth?

**EDIT**: One simple reason to do this is:  if you check the above example, I would prefer `mx.events.MoveEvent.MOVE` (if available) instead of `flash.events.Event.ENTER_FRAME` for performance issues.

thanks..

Comment: If you want to create a class / library wit no Flex Dependencies, don't use any Flex specific classes in it.

Comment: Understand first... The point of doing this is: When you create a large custom helper library; you definitely want to be able to use it in both AS3 and Flex projects. Otherwise, you have to write the clone of the whole library for Flex. Do not tell people what they need. Down-vote only if the question is useless or unclear. If it is useless, tell us why.

Comment: I posted a more in depth answer to tell you why the question is useless; and why the mxLibrariresSupported() function will never throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping over whether this is a good idea or not, the solution is straightforward:

```
var isFlexFound:Boolean = true;

try{
    var myClass:Class = getDefinitionByName("mx.core.UIComponent") as Class;
}catch(err:*){
    isFlexFound = false;
}
trace("Flex Found: " + isFlexFound);
```

Comment: That said, you won't be able to have type-safety if you didn't compile with the FlexSDK.  You'll have to declare types as * or Object.  As soon as you import mx.* into your project, the compiler will bundle everything in.

Comment: Others may need this or not but this was what I needed in the concept that my library would work. And this works great. Question asked, answer received.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import mx.events in a pure AS3 project, so could you have some sort of mapping function like:

```
public static MX_RESIZE_EVENT : String = "RESIZE";
public static FLASH_RESIZE_EVENT : String = "RESIZE";

public static function getResizeEventName() : String {
     return mxLibrariesSupported ? MX_RESIZE_EVENT : FLASH_RESIZE_EVENT;
}

public static function listenToPositionAndSize(control:DisplayObject):void
{
     control.addEventListener(getResizeEventName(), onControlResize);
}
```

There isn't anyway to dynamically import packages, so I think you will be stuck doing something like this. This solution is brittle in that it relies on you hand-copying the event type strings from their respective classes, meaning that if they ever change in the framework the mapping will break (as will your handlers).

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I'll definitely use this but actually I'm searching for a better approach that will replace the `mxLibrariesSupported` function. OR do you think that's the only way?

Comment: I think it is the only way. If you are in a pure AS3 project you can't import mx.events.*, so I doubt you'll be able to avoid this. Could you have a base library where this is an interface and then implement it in two separate projects (AS3 / Flex), thus preserving the ability to import what you need? That sounds possible but a bit of a headache. I doubt they will change the basic event constants so I'd probably stick with the original option.

Comment: Yes but, in fact if you use full package statements such as: `var sp:mx.core.FlexSprite;` instead of `var sp:FlexSprite;`, you don't have to import anything. So you can use that inside a method (like `mxLibrariesSupported()`) without importing the package. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think the mxLibrariesSupported method can be successfully implemented to do what @radgar wants.  This approach still seems limited because in the event handler, you'd probably want to access the proper event.  You can't conditionally change event argument types at run time.

Comment: My previous comment is only about using full package names instead of using import statements. `mxLibrariesSupported()` method will not compile.

Answer (score 1):

This question shows a distinct misunderstanding of how the Flex Compiler works, and I believe what you're trying to do is futile and makes no sense.

Classes used in the code are compiled into the SWC.  If you reference / import Flex specific classes, then those classes will be compiled into the SWC, and then your final SWF.  So, using this library with Flex dependencies you will never experience a situation where mxLibrariesSupported() causes an error; because the mere fact that you reference the FlexEvent means it will be compiled into your final SWC.

In your comment, you mentioned that you can't use an AS3 class in a Flex project without needing to duplicate it to add Flex dependencies.  I have no idea why.  The Flex Framework is entirely built in AS3 and any AS3 code in a SWC can be used in a Flex project w/o any changes.  I've done it.

If you want to use something in non-Flex projects, don't put AS3 dependencies in the library.

Comment: The `mxLibrariesSupported()` method won't compile that's why I asked if there is a better way. If there is no way (which seems so); then the answer would be "NO-WAY".But believe me if there was a way; many coders would use it 'cause it would be a great way to write common classes that work both in pure-as3 and flex.But still there is one thing that I've learned from your answer, which is; even the code inside try-catch statement still gets compiled into the final SWC. I would think that at run-time; if the necessary dependencies are not found in SWC, I would get an error. So thanks for that..

Comment: @Radgar Perhaps I misunderstood the comment on your question; but I still see you saying the same thing I originally interpreted: "it would be a great way to write common classes that work both in pure-as3 and flex."  You can do that; many people do.  Just don't include any dependencies on the Flex Framework.

Comment: "I would think that at run-time; if the necessary dependencies are not found in SWC, I would get an error."  That should never happen; because if the dependency is not there, the class will never compile.  At run-time all needed dependencies are already compiled into the final SWF.  You might be able to mock something up w/ Interfaces, but I think a lot of code [such as something that creates and dispatches events] would be difficult if not impossible to write without including the event class in the SWC.